# Disabling Live Player in Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I would like to disable the Xamarin Live player in Visual Studio.

[image]

The Live Player is no use of me since my app uses CustomRenderers and other things that the Live Player can't do.

It's time-consuming to always select the correct device for debugging.
And quite frequently I accidentally use the Player.

Is there a way to completely uninstall, or if not, disable the Xamarin Live Player?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Visual Studio for Windows

`Tools` / `Options` / `Xamarin` / `Other` :

Uncheck Enable Xamarin Live Player

[image]

#### Visual Studio for Mac

App Menu / Preferences / Xamarin Live Player :

Uncheck Enable Xamarin Live Player

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated!